# Jquery sliding animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is going to sound a bit vague, but i'll try and be as clear as possible.

I have this section of jquery that animates a slide down box.

```
$(function() {
    $('.toggler').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('div').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

I'm just wondering if there is a way to stop when the user wiggles their mouse over and over the box, the box pops up and down then up and down for the amount of times the users mouse has crossed the box.

I hope that's clear.

HTML

```
<div class ="expandableboxes">
    <div class="toggler"> This is the title 
        <div> This is the content to be toggled </div>
    </div>

    <div class="toggler"> This is the title 
        <div> This is the content to be toggled </div>
    </div>

    <div class="toggler"> This is the title 
        <div> This is the content to be toggled </div>
    </div>

    <div class="toggler"> This is the title 
        <div> This is the content to be toggled </div>
    </div>

    <div class="toggler"> This is the title 
        <div> This is the content to be toggled </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is a syntax error in your js. you forgot the `});` at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `stop` and `slideDown` functions.

> ### [`.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)
>
> Description: Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toggler').hover(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass("toggler")) { return; }
    $(this).find('div').stop().slideDown(1000, "easeOutBounce");
  });
});
```

```css
.toggler > div { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js"></script>
<div class="expandableboxes">
  <div class="toggler">This is the title
    <div>This is the content to be toggled</div>
  </div>

  <div class="toggler">This is the title
    <div>This is the content to be toggled</div>
  </div>

  <div class="toggler">This is the title
    <div>This is the content to be toggled</div>
  </div>

  <div class="toggler">This is the title
    <div>This is the content to be toggled</div>
  </div>

  <div class="toggler">This is the title
    <div>This is the content to be toggled</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the user does wiggle the cursor over the box now, it will only pop partially down in the future.

Comment: @TobyCannon How do you want to animate the boxes?

Comment: Just so they slide down, is there a way to perhaps make it look as if they bounce when they've been extended? @Ionică Bizău

Comment: I can see it works when I run the code on this website, however on mine the boxes now do not expand. Here's my html, css and js http://jsfiddle.net/5sde40wx/

Comment: @TobyCannon I included jQuery, jQuery UI and replaced `stop` with `stop()` (it's a function). http://jsfiddle.net/5sde40wx/1/

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work when I try and run it locally. Do I need any more than     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js"></script>

Comment: @TobyCannon Press <F12>, then go to Console and see if you have any errors. If so, paste them here.

Comment: There are no errors listed. The boxes appear already dropped down and do not change state

Comment: @TobyCannon Do you want to slide up too?

Comment: Thanks so much, got it to work, at the moment they start in the down state on page load though, any ideas?

Comment: They still are in the down state when I load the local html file, is there a way to manually set it so they are hidden on page load?

Comment: @TobyCannon Probably you forgot to add the CSS rule `.toggler > div { display: none; }`.

Comment: Ah yes, had this there but was just commenting out different sections of the css to see if it had an effect and forgot to save. Works like a dream thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid frequent pops up and down use mouseenter

```
$(function() {
 $('.toggler'). mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).find('div').slideToggle();
 });
});
```

See the demo [here](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)